# Python import module using command prompt

Tags: python, import, module, command-prompt

I have a code in Python 2.7 write using the IDLE PyCharm on Windows 7 OS. Running inside the IDLE i have no problem to import all modules. When i run with the command prompt of windows i get this error message:

```
C:\Users\samsung>C:\PythonScript\TOOL.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonScript\TOOL.py", line 5, in <module
>
    import ogr
ImportError: No module named ogr
```

I can import this module with the IDLE without problem.

Comment: Is this `ogr` module installed from pypi (`pip`) or is it a module you wrote whose .py file is in the same directory as `TOOL.py`?

Comment: is your Python version the same? check it with `import sys;print(sys.version_info)` or `python --version`

Comment: Thanks Karan, I installed this module by "Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages" page (see GDAL) and it's not in the in the same directory of TOOL.py

Comment: @User thanks: sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0) and my Python version is 2.7.5

Comment: Then it is could be the directory problem as Karan Goel said. Did yu resolve the problem?

Comment: @User nope i did not resolve :(

Comment: What is `import ogr;print(ogr.__file__)`? And what is `import sys;print(sys.path)` in both cases?

Comment: @User print(ogr.__file__) gives C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ogr.pyc and print(sys.path) gives
['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2.7.3\\helpers\\pydev', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\progressbar-2.3-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PythonScript']

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37105/discussion-between-gianni-and-user)